# Even if the second SSL certificate is set to Google Cloud Platform load balancer, it disappears from the target

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a question about the Google Cloud Platform load balancer.

I can register an SSL certificate separately in the front-end settings. Now I want to set up a second SSL so that the same website can log in with HTTPS from the two domains.

About 15 minutes after registration, the second SSL certificate was also valid, and even if you accessed with a new domain name, you could access HTTPS.

However, after a while, the second SSL setting automatically disappears from the GCP load balancer setting, and even if you access the domain of the HTTPS certificate, the error "NET :: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" is displayed on the screen.

How can I set up a second SSL certificate to work?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTPS load balancer uses [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to determine which certificate to present to the client, based on the domain name in the TLS handshake. The load balancer selects a certificate whose common name (CN) or subject alternative name (SAN) matches the SNI hostname specified by the client.

If the client does not use SNI, or if the client uses a domain name that does not match the Common Name (CN) in one of the certificates, the load balancer negotiates SSL using the first certificate (primary) listed in frontend configuration and fallback occurs.

If the client uses SNI to provide a hostname during the TLS (SSL) handshake, the load balancer uses the certificate associated with that hostname.

Here is an **[example](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates?hl=en_US&_ga=2.16053682.-547596003.1572292940#multiple-example)** of how multiple SSL certificates work with HTTPS load balancing.

Comment: I received the comments and set up the GCP load balancer again. There was the following difference between the result of the curl command executed while the second SSL certificate was sent and the result of executing the curl command after the certificate was revoked a few minutes later.

success
`subjectAltName: host "second.domain.com" matched cert's "second.domain.com"`

several minutes after
`subjectAltName does not match second.domain.com`

I think that there is no problem solving with the domain name.
But I don't know why the second SSL certificate is revoked in minutes.

Comment: Check your certificates status if ACTIVE or PROVISIONING, in GCP cloud shell by using the command: **gcloud beta compute ssl-certificates list**

Comment: All SSL certificates registered in GCP were displayed, but the MANAGED_STATUS column was empty for all certificates.

Comment: Make sure that the DNS records for your domains must reference the IP address of your load balancer's target proxy. If everything is correct, provisioning may take from 30 to 60 minutes.

Comment: The registration of the domain in DNS has been completed a few weeks ago, and I have confirmed that both the domain name I want to add this time and the domain name that is already running show the same IP address using the dig command (on local console and Google cloud shell).

Comment: I created Secret and applied Ingress, but I get an error even if I access it with the second domain with the curl command.

Comment: Are you using wildcards? Is your domain name length within 64 bytes?

Comment: No wildcard are used, and the domain name within 64 bytes.

Comment: Even if you create Secret and apply Ingress, [GKE will overwrite your changes][1] (check Important note) and this might be the reason cert is revoking. Also, verify if your [configuration][2] is correct. If you still face issues, further troubleshooting may required. For that reach out to Google cloud support [3](require support plan) in order to investigate your project. 

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress
[2]: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl [3]: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs

Comment: Check the setting of Ingress, but still I will try to use the GCP of the support plan as long as this still does not resolve the problem. Thanks for answering various questions, Mr. Gagandeep.

Comment: Hello @kouki. Could you resolve this problem? I was previously using self-managed wildcard cert. Now trying to use google-managed specific cert. But when i added the google-managed cert, it keeps disappearing after few minutes/hours.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, simply sign off a certificate matching both domains, with the same IP.

Comment: I set two SSL certificates on the load balancer to show the same IP with different domain names, but after a few minutes, the added certificate disappears from the configuration.